# Why does the photon in Compton Scattering have a minimum frequency/maximum wavelenght?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, kinematics

Using conservation of four-momentum one finds that, with respect to the angle of deviation of the photon from its original direction $\theta$, the wavelength and frequency of the emitted photon are:

$
\nu' = \frac{\nu}{1 + \frac{h\nu}{mc^2}(1 - \cos\theta)} \qquad \lambda' = \lambda + \lambda_C(1 - \cos\theta)
$

This functions are monotone and have a maximum (minimum) in $\theta=0$ (where $\nu'=\nu,\lambda'=\lambda$) and a minimum (maximum) in $\theta=\pi$ (backscattering), where:

$
\nu' = \frac{\nu}{1 + 2\frac{h\nu}{mc^2}} \qquad \lambda' = \lambda + 2\lambda_C
$

I would expect that the limiting case of scattering is absorption, where $\nu' = 0,\lambda'\to\infty$ but instead there's a finite gap between absorption and the limiting case of scattering.

This reasoning uses only kinematics so the result should be intuitive and even predictable before doing the calculation but I can't get my head around why it should the case.

Can anyone explain how one should expect this result beforehand or at all?